# How to get response through post back using web method in aspx page using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am struggling to get response from aspx page using web method through ajax, but response from web method directly goes to error function and throws an internal server error(500).

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home.aspx/getAnalyticsData",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                var data = result.hasOwnProperty('d') ? result.d : result;
                alert(data); 
            },
            error:function(xhr){
               alert(data);
            }

});
```

It throws an error,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: You need to check your server logs, as 500 is an internal server-side error.

Comment: Does your method have `[WebMethod]` attribute, and is it static?